# How to add custom jquery validation?

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

How to add custom jquery validation for validating one or two digit number along with * or #,
Eg: *2#, *23#

I have tried the following code but it doesn't meet my requirement,

```
    $.validator.addMethod("shortCodes", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value === "NA" ||
       value.match(/^[0-9,\*#]+$/);
 }, "Please enter only one or two digit number along with(* or #)");
```

Any help will be greatful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $.validator.addMethod("pattern", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || this.patternCheck(value);

}, "Please enter 1 or 2 digit number or number along with special characters(* or #)         (ex:5,55,*5,5#,*55#).");

this.patternCheck = function(value){
    if(value.match(/^[\*#]\d{1,2}?[\*#]$/)){
        return true;
    }else if(value.match(/^[\*#]\d{1,2}$/)){
        return true;
    }else if(value.match(/^\d{1,2}[\*#]$/)){
        return true;
    }else if(value.match(/^\d{1,2}$/)){
        return true;
    }else if(value.match(/^[\*#]$/)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be:

```
/^(NA|[0-9*#]{1,2})$/
```

With this regex you don't need to check for "NA" separately.

Comment: ,thanks its not allowing more than two charaters...my need is maxlength of the field should not be limited  eg:*1#,*23#

Comment: You said "one or two digit number". Please clarify your requirement.

Comment: yes, but i had mentioned one or two digit number along with * or #

Comment: Please describe your requirements PRECISELY. Do the punctuations have to be at the beginning and end, like your examples, or can they be mixed in with the numbers?  Are they required or optional?

Comment: Are #*#12*** and **2## valid? What about *1##2*?

Comment: Sorry,*# can be can be mixed but no puntuations should  repeat, for eg: *2#4,*#3,7#*,*2, 7#,#8,36* etc....not (**33,##56,**#6).

Comment: I don't think that can be done with a regex, other than a complicated disjunction of all the different combinations. I suggest just iterating over the characters and counting the number of digits, *, and #, then checking the totals.